# Why is my data table formatted differently when rendered in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, datatable

I am trying to output a data table in a Shiny web application using the function renderTable. However, the table that is output is formatted differently than the table that is output in my R console. Why is this, and is there a way to fix it so that the Shiny table matches the formatting of the table in R?

I am using the following dataset linked here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/shubhamgupta012/titanic-dataset/data

Here are the relevant pieces of the code I have used in my attempt to output this table:

```
#Creating UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Modeling Survival Outcomes for Titanic Passengers"),
  
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Data Visualization", fluid=TRUE,
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 
                 #adding sidebar title
                 h2(strong("Display Options")),
                 br(),
                 
                 #select box for variable to display
                 selectInput("select_graph", label=strong("Select a graph to display"),
                             choices = list("Survival Distribution" = 1, "Class Distribution" = 2,
                                            "Sex Distribution" = 3, "Age Distribution" = 4,
                                            "Number of Family Members Aboard Distribution" = 5,
                                            "Fare Distribution" = 6, "Embark Location Distribution" = 7,
                                            "Survival by Class" = 8, "Survival by Sex" = 9,
                                            "Survival by Age" = 10, "Survival by Number of Family Members Aboard" = 11,
                                            "Survival by Fare Paid" = 12, "Survival by Embark Location" = 13), selected=8),
                 br(),
                 
                 #checkbox for displaying descriptive statistics
                 checkboxInput("disp", label=strong("Display descriptive statistics"), value=TRUE),
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput("stats8"),
               )
             )
    )
  )
  
)

# Defining server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$stats8 <- renderTable({
    if(input$disp & input$select_graph == 8){
      class_props <- prop.table(table(titanic$Pclass, titanic$Survived), 1)
      colnames(class_props) <- c("Did Not Survive", "Survived")
      rownames(class_props) <- c("First Class", "Second Class", "Third Class")
      class_props[] <- paste0(as.matrix(round(class_props, 3)*100), '%')
      class_props
    }
  }, rownames=TRUE, colnames=TRUE, bordered=TRUE, spacing="m", width="100%", align="c")
  
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I print the `class_props` table in my R console, it looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kvjpm.png).

However, when I run the application, the rendered table looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzWpr.png)

It seems like the Shiny application is automatically pivoting the data, but I do not want it to do this. Is there a way to fix this issue so that the Shiny output matches the formatting of the R console output?